# Access single variable values globally in magento wihin .php files

Tags: magento-1.9, template, php-5.4, code-analysis

I want to **access** `$brandId` in all other `.php` files in magento.. How do I do it?

```
$brandId = array_search($brand_name, array_map('strtolower',$this->getAvailableBrands())); is in code/core/mybrandpages/Brand/Block/Brandproductlist.php
```

I want to use the same $brandId values in various file as follows without calling that function multiple time.

```
code/core/mybrandpages/Brand/Block/Pager.php
code/core/mybrandpages/Brand/Block/Brandtoolbar.php
```

Answer (score 1):

use Magento Registry

```
$brandId = array_search($brand_name, array_map('strtolower',$this->getAvailableBrands()));
Mage::register('brand-id', $brandId);
```

access that value using below code

```
$brandId = Mage::registry('brand-id');
```

Comment: please put such points on meta site or report it to moderator @TejabhagavanKollepara

Comment: Upps my fault and sry for that @TejabhagavanKollepara

Comment: hey no no sorry bro. why sorry? no problem. sometimes may happen haha